# Google App Engine Console Logs not getting loaded

Tags: google-app-engine, developer-console

Ever since the UI for Google Developers Console have changed. There seems to be a problem while loading the logs for existing Google App Engine project. We are facing this issue for quite some time and sometimes it works for other projects. Does anyone have a knowledge regarding this problem.

Comment: Could you give details about what the the problem is that you are experiencing?

Comment: Logs (Logging) in new Google developer console do not load properly, if I click on "Logging" it is meant to show logs for the current project but nothing happens (the screen is just empty)

Comment: That's not normal. After browser troubleshooting (trying different ones, clearing browser data) I'd suggest posting an issue to https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list, with a screenshot that shows the URL visible.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I think that's the only option left.